# ¿Como soluciono este error al conectar mi base de sql server en Auth0?

Tags: sql-server, nodejs, auth0

**Estuve intentando con el "custom database" de Auth0 usar mi propia base de datos para mi aplicación y me sale este error al probar la conexión:**
*Login failed for user ''.*
Esta es mi configuracion en el custom database - login:

```
function login(email, password, callback) {
  const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
  const sqlserver = require('tedious');

  const Connection = sqlserver.Connection;
  const Request = sqlserver.Request;
  const TYPES = sqlserver.TYPES;


  const connection = sqlserver.connect({
    userName:  'sa',
    password:  'mipassword',
    server:    'miserver',
    options:  {
      port: 1533,
      database: 'midatabase',
      trustServerCertificate: true,
    }
  });

  const query = 'SELECT idUser, usrUsername, usrEmail, usrPassword FROM dbo.Users WHERE usrEmail = ?';



 connection.on('debug', function (text) {
    console.log(text);
  }).on('errorMessage', function (text) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(text, null, 2));
  }).on('infoMessage', function (text) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(text, null, 2));
  });

  connection.on('connect', function (err) {
    if (err) return callback(err);

    const request = new Request(query, function (err, rowCount, rows) {
      if (err || rowCount < 1) return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

      bcrypt.compare(password, rows[0][3].value, function (err, isValid) {
        if (err || !isValid) return callback(err || new WrongUsernameOrPasswordError(email));

        callback(null, {
          user_id: rows[0][0].value,
          nickname: rows[0][1].value,
          email: rows[0][2].value
        });
      });
    });

    request.addParameter('Email', TYPES.VarChar, email);
    connection.execSql(request);
  });
}``
```

*Busque información en la comunidad de auth0 y en la pagina oficial de sql server y no encontré solución.*
*No puedo configurar el SQLServer desde dentro, necesito una solución que pueda agregar en la conexión dentro de auth0 en el bloque de código que deje.*

Comment: Le tuve que sacar la version al tediuos en el require ya que de esa forma rompia antes de conectarse.